# How to use Firebase Auth API to send email verification and check whether the user is verified before logging in

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, firebase-authentication

I am building a react project and I want to know how to use the "VERIFY_EMAIL" request type to send email verification and verify if the user is verified or not.

Comment: is this what your looking for ?? 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth#send_an_authentication_link_to_the_users_email_address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the user logged in, you could just grab the `user = auth().currentUser`, where there is a emailVerfied boolean. Then you just do `user.sendEmailVerification()`. See their docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth

If you want to know if they are verified before logging in (by their email), you would need firebase admin setup: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup. This is the admin docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth